# How to Invoke Method<T>(Func<Action<T>> action) with private type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I hope the code snipped illustrates my issue. 
I need to `Invoke` the `CallEvent` method like it is in the out-commented line.
I have no access to the `ThirdParty` or `AnotherThirdParty` class.
This is as far as I come:

```
public class ThirdParty
{
    private struct MsgType
    { }

    private static void AnotherFunc(MsgType msg)
    { }
}

public class AnotherThirdParty
{
    public static void CallEvent<T>(Func<int, Action<T>> action, T arg)
    { }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Type MsgType = typeof(ThirdParty).GetNestedType(
            "MsgType", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        object msg = Activator.CreateInstance(MsgType);

        MethodInfo CallEvent = typeof(AnotherThirdParty).GetMethod("CallEvent");
        CallEvent = CallEvent.MakeGenericMethod(MsgType);

        MethodInfo AnotherFunc = typeof(ThirdParty).GetMethod(
            "AnotherFunc", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        CallEvent.Invoke(null, new object[] {???, msg});
        //CallEvent<MsgType>((int x) => new Action<MsgType>(AnotherFunc), msg);
        // I can't get my head around how to solve this (Action<msgtype>)
    }
}
```

I also tried:

```
CallEvent.Invoke(null, new object[]
    {
        new Func<int, Action<object>>((int x) =>
            new Action<object>((object y) =>
                AnotherFunc.Invoke(null, new object[] { y }))),
        msg
    });
```

I get the following Exception:

> System.ArgumentException: Object of type
>   'System.Func2[System.Int32,System.Action1[System.Object]]' cannot be
>   converted to type
>   'System.Func2[System.Int32,System.Action1[ThirdParty+MsgType]].

How should I proceed?

Comment: Does `AnotherThirdParty.CallEvent` do anything with the `T` arg (other than send it out over the action)?

Comment: yes, it calls another method `RaiseEvent<T1, T2, T3>(T1 arg1, T3 arg3, Func<T1, Action<T2>> action, T2 arg2) where T1 : int where T3 : int`

Comment: What should the Factory function do? Just return the method on every int or something else?

Comment: @FilipCordas tried to simplify the sample, the real application is a server that notifies all connected clients about some events, if that helps

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public class ThirdParty
{
    private struct MsgType { }
    private static void AnotherFunc(MsgType msg)
    {
        // Inserted to demonstrate getting here
        Console.WriteLine($"HEY: {msg}");
    }
}

public class AnotherThirdParty
{
    public static void CallEvent<T>(Func<int, Action<T>> action, T arg)
    {
        // Inserted to demonstrate calling the func and then
        // the action
        action(12)(arg);
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var msgTypeType = 
        typeof(ThirdParty).GetNestedType("MsgType", BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    // This is the message type we're passing (presumably you'll do more with it)
    var ourMsgTypeArg = Activator.CreateInstance(msgTypeType);

    // Get the reference to the CallEvent method
    var callEventMethod =
        typeof(AnotherThirdParty).GetMethod("CallEvent", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
        .MakeGenericMethod(msgTypeType);

    // Get the reference to the AnotherFunc method
    var anotherFunc =
        typeof(ThirdParty).GetMethod("AnotherFunc", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

    // Build the func to pass along to CallEvent
    var func = CreateFunc(msgTypeType, anotherFunc);

    // Call the CallEvent<MsgType> method.
    callEventMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {
        func,
        ourMsgTypeArg
    });
}

private static Delegate CreateFunc(Type msgType, MethodInfo anotherFunc)
{
    // The func takes an int
    var intArg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));

    // The action takes a msgType
    var msgTypeArg = Expression.Parameter(msgType);

    // Represent the call out to "AnotherFunc"
    var call = Expression.Call(null, anotherFunc, msgTypeArg);

    // Build the action to just make the call to "AnotherFunc"
    var action = Expression.Lambda(call, msgTypeArg);

    // Build the func to just return the action
    var func = Expression.Lambda(action, intArg);

    // Compile the chain and send it out
    return func.Compile();
}
```

This code functions as you've requested and prints the following:

```
HEY: UserQuery+ThirdParty+MsgType
```

Comment: Same problem I had with the method not doing anything. But what ever he is doing this is probably the wrong way of doing it.

Comment: @FilipCordas can you elaborate, as this does work. The method as posted by OP wouldn't do anything, as I imagine they just wanted to have a simple-enough block of code.

Comment: I was not clear in what I meant the answer is grate. The wrong part is having to do this in the first palce.

Comment: @FilipCordas Agreed, having to call private methods in third party libraries is usually sketchy, but sometimes necessary unfortunately :(

Comment: Do you need the extra lambda in `action`?

Comment: @NetMage: Yes, the parameter type is `Func<int,Action<T>>`

Comment: I see - you replaced the `new Action<>` with the lambda. Nice.

Comment: Took me some time to debug why the test works but my plugin crashes, apparently this causes the 'AnotherFunc' to lose its attributes

Comment: @timohehnen that's odd, it shouldn't do... all you're doing is calling it. It could be it's doing something weird in there, perhaps update your question / ask another (and link it) with the disassembled code in AnotherFunc and the exception you're getting?

Comment: Will do on Monday,  though it's going to be quite some code then

Answer (score 2):

This seems to run:

```
    MethodInfo miCreateDelegate = typeof(MethodInfo).GetMethod("CreateDelegate", new[] { typeof(Type), typeof(Object) });
    var ActionType = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(MsgType);
    var lambdabody = Expression.Convert(Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(AnotherFunc), miCreateDelegate, new[] { Expression.Constant(ActionType), Expression.Constant(null) }), ActionType);
    var intparm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(lambdabody, intparm);

    CallEvent.Invoke(null, new object[] {
        lambda.Compile(),
        msg
    });
```

A more complete answer is how did I generate this? I used LINQPad to compile a simpler, similar expression substituting `string` for `MsgType` into an `Expression`:

```
public static void afunc(string x) { }

Expression<Func<int, Action<string>>> lambda = (int x) => new Action<string>(afunc);
```

Then I used the LINQPad `Dump()` function to output the expression tree.

```
lambda.Dump();
```

Then some spelunking in MSDN Expression documentation gave me the right static methods to create the pieces. I already knew how to instantiate generic types from an extension method for LINQPad that creates anonymous types on the fly to extend `Dump()` to exclude fields from anonymous objects, and I knew how to create lambdas from an extension method that extends LINQ with a proper SQL-translatable Left and Right Join operation.

Comment: This is good, but it involves the casting to chuck around into CreateDelegate, it can be done without it. (also good to see someone else playing with Expression :P)

Comment: I added more explanation, but this is how the compiler converts a lambda call to `new Action<>`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53cz7sc6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method to construct an `Action<MsgType>` object. Construct `Func<int,Action<T>>` using [`Expression.Lambda<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var actionType = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(MsgType);
var funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(int), actionType);
var p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
var p2 = Expression.Parameter(actionType);
var delegate = Expression.Constant(Delegate.CreateDelegate(actionType, AnotherFunc), funcType);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(delegate, p1, p2);
CallEvent.Invoke(null, new object[] {
    lambda.Compile()
,   msg
});
```

Comment: System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.Action`1[ThirdParty+MsgTyype]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Func`2[System.Int32,System.Action`1[ThirdParty+MsgTyype]]'.

Comment: Missing the Func<int, Action<object>> part.. Note this wont work on .net standard 1.1

Comment: @timohehnen This should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

This will work and will print an A but the function factory is a mistery to me so I just returned the created delegate. And this is compatible with .net standard 1.1

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             Type MsgType = typeof(ThirdParty).GetNestedType(
                "MsgType", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        object msg = Activator.CreateInstance(MsgType);

        MethodInfo CallEvent = typeof(AnotherThirdParty).GetMethod("CallEvent");
        CallEvent = CallEvent.MakeGenericMethod(MsgType);

        MethodInfo AnotherFunc = typeof(ThirdParty).GetMethod(
            "AnotherFunc", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        var actionType = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(MsgType);

        var actionDelegate = AnotherFunc.CreateDelegate(actionType);

        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
        var funcDelegate = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Constant(actionDelegate),param).Compile();

        CallEvent.Invoke(null, new []{ funcDelegate, msg });


        Console.ReadLine();

        }

        public class ThirdParty
        {
            private struct MsgType
            { }

            private static void AnotherFunc(MsgType msg)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A");
            }
        }

        public class AnotherThirdParty
        {
            public static void CallEvent<T>(Func<int, Action<T>> action, T arg)
            {
                action(1)(arg);
            }
        }
```